# How to add a button to a Datagrid under the 3.5 compact net framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm developing for a smart device (windows ce 6.5) under the 3.5 net compact framework.

What i'm trying to do is to add a simple button to a DataGrid (not a datagridview, they don't exist for this framework).

Since there is no Button for the DataGrid you have to develop your own control.

I read the following code to give me an idea

https://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_combobox_in_datagrid.html

But once i got to the part of actually adding the control to the DataGrid, i hit a roadblock since i cant seem to find the way to access the parent.

In the original code they do access it thru the TextBox reference.

```
// The Edit event is raised when the user sets the focus to the cell
        // containing the combobox. In this event the dimensions of the combobox
        // are set and an event handler is assigned to handle scrolling of the combobox.
        protected override void Edit(
            CurrencyManager source,
            int rowNum,
            Rectangle bounds,
            bool readOnly,
            string instantText,
            bool cellIsVisible)
        {
            base.Edit(source, rowNum, bounds, readOnly, instantText, cellIsVisible);

            // Attach the Combobox to the same Parent Control
            // as the TextBox of the DataGrid
            myComboBox.Parent = this.TextBox.Parent;

}
```

But in the compact .net framework the DataGridTextBoxColumn class does not have that reference.

This is my current control.

```
public class DataGridButtonColumn:DataGridTextBoxColumn
    {
        private Button _button;

        public DataGridButtonColumn()
        {
            _button = new Button();
            _button.Width = 50; //default size
            _button.BackColor = Color.Gray; //default color
        }

        public Button DataGridButton
        {
            get { return _button; }
        }

        protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source, int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight)
        {
            base.Paint(g, bounds, source, rowNum, backBrush, foreBrush, alignToRight);
        }
    }
```

Any idea on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596067/attach-button-to-column-datagrid-in-c-sharp-compact-framework-net-2-0 with a link to MS forum. And duplicate as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338171/how-to-add-a-new-column-to-delete-a-datagrids-row-windows-mobile

Comment: Thanks @josef. Most of that points to the 2.0 CF. I was hopping for an easier way in the 3.5 CF but it seem that wont be case.